# How to prevent the automatic startup of VBoxHeadless on Mac?

Tags: virtualbox

I Install VirtualBox for Mac but I do not use it.  The VBoxHeadless process still takes a lot of memory.  How to stop it permanently and prevent from the automatic startup?

Comment: Is it set as a login code? If so it will start every time you start your account.

Comment: @jmh, what do you mean by a login code?

Comment: you can set certain apps to launch at login or startup. Maybe your app is set to do this?

Comment: I do not see this setup in System Preferences

Comment: goto system preferences, Users and Groups and click on login items tab. See if you app is listed.

Comment: It is not listed there